# I have a very strange question with xamarin.form and libvlcsharp

Tags: xamarin.forms, libvlcsharp

When I create LibVLC and MediaPlayer objects in the constructor and play the video, there is only sound but no image. When I create LibVLC and MediaPlayer objects in the'Play' function, there are sounds and images. I don't want to create a MediaPlayer object every time the play function is called. what should I do?

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using LibVLCSharp.Shared;
using static Xamarin.Essentials.Permissions;


namespace MediaElement
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the main viewmodel.
    /// </summary>
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Property changed event
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="MainViewModel"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Core.Initialize();
            LibVLC = new LibVLC();
            MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(LibVLC) { EnableHardwareDecoding = true };
        }

        
        

        private LibVLC _libVLC;
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the <see cref="LibVLCSharp.Shared.LibVLC"/> instance.
        /// </summary>
        public LibVLC LibVLC
        {
            get => _libVLC;
            private set => Set(nameof(LibVLC), ref _libVLC, value);
        }

        private MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer;
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the <see cref="LibVLCSharp.Shared.MediaPlayer"/> instance.
        /// </summary>
        public MediaPlayer MediaPlayer
        {
            get => _mediaPlayer;
            private set => Set(nameof(MediaPlayer), ref _mediaPlayer, value);
        }

               

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize LibVLC and playback when page appears
        /// </summary>
        public void Play(String path)
        {
                MediaPlayer.Play(new LibVLCSharp.Shared.Media(LibVLC, new Uri(path)));             
        }

        

        private void Set<T>(string propertyName, ref T field, T value)
        {
            if (field == null && value != null || field != null && !field.Equals(value))
            {
                field = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me see how to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69210874/libvlcsharp-will-get-stuck-playing-specific-videos-on-any-platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only sent half of your code, we don't know how you are using your VideoView control.

As a general rule of thumb:

- How do you attach the MediaPlayer to your view?
- Do you properly wait for the view to be visible before calling Play?
- Have a look at the samples [here](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/tree/3.x/samples) and compare to see what you did wrong.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: I have share all the project. please get it at [http://steelsoft.site/quPlayer.zip].
Help me solve the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: the project is at http://steelsoft.site/quPlayer.zip

Comment: Sorry, I don't click links to zip files hosted on domains I don't trust. Moreover, on StackOverflow, you have to include every details in the question to avoid link rot.

Comment: in the page, I codes below:
MasterDetailPage1Detail.xaml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MediaElement"
             xmlns:vlc="clr-namespace:LibVLCSharp.Forms.Shared;assembly=LibVLCSharp.Forms"
             x:Class="quPlayer.MasterDetailPage1Detail"
             Title="Menu">


    <vlc:MediaPlayerElement MediaPlayer="{Binding MediaPlayer}" EnableRendererDiscovery="True"/>
</ContentPage>

Comment: using LibVLCSharp.Shared;
using MediaElement;

namespace quPlayer
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MasterDetailPage1Detail : ContentPage
    {
        MainViewModel mainViewModel;
        public MasterDetailPage1Detail()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
            this.BindingContext = mainViewModel;
        }        
        

    }
}

Comment: Please edit your question instead and paste your code as code blocks. Why did you enable renderer discovery?